# How would you make two <div>s overlap?

Tags: css, html, overlap

I need two divs to look a bit like this:

```
    |               |
 ---|    LOGO       |------------------------
|   |_______________|  LINKS                |
|             CONTENT                       |
```

What's the neatest/most elegant way of making them overlap neatly? The logo will have a fixed height and width and will be touching the top edge of the page.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I might approach it like so (CSS and HTML):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#logo {
  position: absolute; /* Reposition logo from the natural layout */
  left: 75px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#content {
  margin-top: 100px; /* Provide buffer for logo */
}
#links {
  height: 75px;
  margin-left: 400px; /* Flush links (with a 25px "padding") right of logo */
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
</div>
<div id="content">
  
  <div id="links">dssdfsdfsdfsdf</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any way to make content just avoid the space used by the logo?

Comment: hmm can you clarify? i take that to mean you just want the logo above the content? if so that's just a normal flow of divs (so remove left, top, position from #logo). i have a feeling you mean something else though! :)

Comment: I think what was meant was to have the content (text) wrap around the logo

Comment: ah hmm, i'm pretty sure not. the problem being an element can be floated, or positioned, but not both. until they develop some sort of float: center idea...

Answer (score 113):

Just use negative margins, in the second div say:

```
<div style="margin-top: -25px;">
```

And make sure to set the z-index property to get the layering you want.

Comment: This is by far the simplest method, and can easily be adapted for overlapping footers by using margin-bottom on the content of a page. Thanks!

Comment: this solution seems to depend on DOCTYPE, doesn't it? because it didn't work with HTML5 DOCTYPE when I tried.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, position absolute tends to cause problems.

Comment: It's not possible to use z-index without set position to something different that static. Unfortunately, this answer not let you choose the z-order.

Comment: This is the simplest and clean solution. Love it:)

Answer (score 6):

With absolute or relative positioning, you can do all sorts of overlapping. You've probably want the logo to be styled as such:

```
div#logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px; // or whatever
}
```

Note: absolute position has its eccentricities. You'll probably have to experiment a little, but it shouldn't be too hard to do what you want.

Comment: Would that cause the logo to overlap the text where links is though? Or would it push the links over to the side?

Comment: No, absolute effectively removes the tag from the flow. It would be as if it weren't there.

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS, you set the logo div to position absolute, and set the z-order to be above the second div.

```
#logo
{
    position: absolute:
    z-index: 2000;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the logo to take space, you are probably better of floating it left and then moving down the content using margin, sort of like this:

```
#logo {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 20px;
}

#content {
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

or whatever margin you want.