# Static Google Maps Custom Icons

Tags: javascript, maps

I've been looking for a way to add custom markers to a static Google map. I know the API doesn't provide the functionality, but I was wondering if there are any third party scripts that would do this. If not, how would I place my custom transparent images onto the static map?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by static, but it's not hard to put custom images on the map as markers. It does not require any serverside code if that's what you mean.

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/web/examples-tutorials-custom-icons-for-markers

Comment: I already have a normal google map with custom icons that I want to show as a static google map. See this link:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each image in a div tag, overlay the div where you want it over the map, and use the

```
z-index
```

Property to specify ordering. Done and Done.

Check out this link

[How would you make two <div>s overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270493/how-would-you-make-two-divs-overlap)