# two divs over lapping

Tags: css, image, html, stack

So i am trying to do something similar to ([How would you make two <div>s overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270493/how-would-you-make-two-divs-overlap)) but put a lot more things at the top of my website, that would include a few div layers. So i want to move an image to the top to be fixed, then over the image i want to put links with menus, as well as a music player iframe with some now playing text next to it...

its in wordpress, so i have all the div things, just not the way to orient them and the css.

Rough draft of what it would look like:

```
 ____________________________________________________________
|  [           -Logo fixed to top of site-                ]  |
|  [                  [Menu div]                          ]  |
|  [                                                      ]  |
|  [      [music player div]   [html/java div]            ]  |
|  [______________________________________________________]  |
|                                                            |
|                                                            |
|                       [Content]                            ]
```

Edit: What i am trying to achieve is at (http://ngaradio.org) the "member area", "featured Artist" links are in the right place, right on the yellow, but i want to bring them up front.
then i'd like to grab the iframe at the bottom and put it on top too. so far its not working out

Comment: What's your question? Just how to do it? It would be good to have a specific question. Right now it sounds like you're asking us to write it all out, or basically do it, for you.

Comment: im sorry. it send before i could add more. am i to post the css and div i got so far to see what im doing wrong? or link website as example?

Answer (score 1):

The element you want to show overlapped, you need to give it z-index higher and vice verca for  behind elements use lower z-index.

Example- If i have two pictures `#Img1` & `#Img2` , from now i will overlap image two over image one.How to do it-

```
#Img1{
z-index:1;
}
 #Img2{
z-index:2;
}
```

Overlapping image should have higher rate of z-index.

Comment: so index 1 would be ontop of 2? or the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

[I've had a go at what I think you want. Excuse the terrible colours.](http://jsbin.com/oyemun/1)

Edit: Use z-index