# <iframe> video embed overlaps modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

There's a page on my website where I have embedded a livestream from [twitch.tv](http://twitch.tv) and I am experiencing some issues with the livestream overlapping content that it shouldn't. If the user tries to login or register while on that page, then the embedded video will place itself on top on the modal/dialog that opens. The modal is created with Bootstrap 3.

It looks like this:
[image]

The iframe embed looks like this:

```
iframe src="https://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf?channel=imaqtpie" frameborder="0"
```

Anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to probably look at the CSS `z-index` attribute.

You can manually set them in the order you want, however beware of any overiding css coming from the the boostrap class modal.

Although I think it is just the video that needs a lower z-index, as modals are usually given higher values.
e.g.

```
<iframe style='z-index:0' ...
```

More on this SO post: [how to control div overlapping in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440391/how-to-control-div-overlapping-in-html)

Fun tutorial if you have the time: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/what-you-may-not-know-about-the-z-index-property--webdesign-16892