# How to make a div overlap other

Tags: html, css

Well if you see that if there are two `divs`

```
<div id="red">
</div>
<div id="blue">
</div>

#red{
    height: 100px;
    width:20px;
    border: 1px;
}
#blue{
    height: 100px;
}
```

They are rendered as first red will be displayed then blue.

Is it possible that red div actually come at position of blue div but blue div stays on the same position?

Comment: try using positioning in css

Comment: Try nesting the `div` if it is okay or you can position them using css.

Comment: [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270493/how-would-you-make-two-divs-overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270493/how-would-you-make-two-divs-overlap) , [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440391/how-to-control-div-overlapping-in-html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440391/how-to-control-div-overlapping-in-html) refer these and there are more other posts on stack itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `position: absolute;` for the red div will cause it to "float", and then the blue div will start at the same location as the red one.

See code snippet:

```css
#red {
  height: 100px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
#blue {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="red">
</div>
<div id="blue">
</div>
```

If your intention was to create a 100px empty space above it all, then you can add `margin-top: 100px;` to the #blue css rule.